# Unable to post data to nodejs server using C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am trying to send data to node server using C#. Here is the code:

Node + Express:

```
var host = "127.0.0.1";
var port = 1337;
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(request, response){ //root dir
    response.send("Hello!!");
});

app.post("/build", function(request, response){ //root dir

    response.send("This is the post method");
});

app.listen(port, host);
```

C# side:

```
using System.Net.Http;

            const string urlTemplate = "http://localhost:1337/build";
            var userQuery = new User();
            userQuery.Name = "Test";
            userQuery.Location= "Test Location";
            userQuery.Age= 26;

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(600000);
            var task = client.PostAsJsonAsync(urlTemplate, userQuery);
            var result = task.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I am able to get the response from the server. But when I try to say `request.body` to get the `posted` information back, `request.body is undefined`.

This is how the request object looks:
[image]

This is how `query and params` looks:
[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: In your app.post callback, what happens when you log request? Do you see a body object on that? If not, what do you see in the request object?

Comment: @Brant: see the updated question

Comment: What do you have in your params and query bjects on that request? From the Node side of things, I believe you're in good shape. I think it's an issue with the POST request from C#... I'm interested to see if the data you're trying to send in the body is getting inserted in the query obj.

Comment: @Brant: it looks empty. I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are trying to access the body posted to the node server, you need to use the body-parser middleware for this. See below:

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```